# WebAPI mixed authentication with OWIN Tokens and windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, windows-authentication, bearer-token

I am looking for a way to combine Windows Authentication and Identity/token based authentication. I have a Web API that currently uses OWIN to authenticate with Bearer tokens via the /token path and the ASP Membership database. The application that currently accesses this is external and will use a login form to log in.

The second administration application will be internal and I would like to utilize the same Web API RestFul service and allow windows authentication to it.

Is there a way to allow OWIN to allow both options for authentication? or do I need to do the Windows Authentication in another layer and have that layer call the WebAPI with a token?

Comment: Hi @gcoleman0828 Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: Hey @SergioLópez. Yes we did end up with an interesting solution for this. In the end, we went with creating an Authorize filter/attribute that we could place on any of the actions in the WebApi. This allowed us the ability to intercept the IIS pipeline and check if you had a token in the header or not. If it did, we use that and allow the normal OWIN process to occur. If it didn't then, we used the internal Windows authentication.

Comment: Thanks !! :) we will give it a try